# Convert incomplete 12h datetime-like strings into appropriate datetime type

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I've got a pandas Series containing datetime-like strings with 12h format, but without the *am/pm* abbreviations. It covers an entire month of data :

```
40    01/01/2017 11:51:00
41    01/01/2017 11:51:05
42    01/01/2017 11:55:05
43    01/01/2017 11:55:10
44    01/01/2017 11:59:30
45    01/01/2017 11:59:35
46    02/01/2017 12:00:05
47    02/01/2017 12:00:10
48    02/01/2017 12:13:20
49    02/01/2017 12:13:25
50    02/01/2017 12:24:50
51    02/01/2017 12:24:55
52    02/01/2017 12:33:30
Name: TS, dtype: object
(318621,) # shape
```

My goal is to convert it to datetime format, so as to obtain the appropriate unix timestamps values, and make comparisions/arithmetics with other datetime data with, this time, 24h format. So I already tried this :

```
pd.to_datetime(df.TS, format = '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S') # %I for 12h format
```

Which outputs me :

```
64     2017-01-02 00:46:50
65     2017-01-02 00:46:55
66     2017-01-02 01:01:00
67     2017-01-02 01:01:05
68     2017-01-02 01:05:00
```

But the am/pm informations are not taken into account. I know that, as a rule, the am/pm first have to be specified in the strings, then one can use *dt.dt.strptime()* or *pd.to_datetime()* to parse them with the %p indicator.

So I wanted to know if there's an other way to deal with this issue through *datetime* or *pandas* *datetime* modules ? Or, do I have to manualy add the abbreviations 'am/pm' before the parsing ?

Comment: Should it always be parsed as PM?

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive If you refer to the timestamp in the example, yes. I said 'still parsed' because I thought the %I in the format call would have considered the am/pm informations, but I know there's %p to indicate them. But it has to be specified in the str before the conversion.

Comment: So why not just add a "PM" suffix to your dates and parse them?

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive I could, but i'm dealing with a Series of 300 000 datetimes str (one month of data with basically one datetime every 5 seconds). So I have to write a function which indicates when to add 'AM'/'PM' suffixes ? Is there no way to identify it during the parsing ?

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive I think I misunderstood your question. My pandas Series contains 300 000 datetime strings of the 12h format I just mentioned, with a 5 seconds frequency per line. So there is a mix of AM and PM. The data shall not always be parsed as PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data in 5 second intervals throughout multiple days.  The desired end format is like this (with AM/PM column we need to add, because Pandas cannot possibly guess, since it looks at one value at a time):

```
31/12/2016 11:59:55 PM
01/01/2017 12:00:00 AM
01/01/2017 12:00:05 AM
01/01/2017 11:59:55 AM
01/01/2017 12:00:00 PM
01/01/2017 12:59:55 PM
01/01/2017 01:00:00 PM
01/01/2017 01:00:05 PM
01/01/2017 11:59:55 PM
02/01/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

First, we can parse the whole thing without AM/PM info, as you already showed:

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(df.TS, format = '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S')
```

We have a small problem: 12:00:00 is parsed as noon, not midnight.  Let's normalize that:

```
ts[ts.dt.hour == 12] -= pd.Timedelta(12, 'h')
```

Now we have times from 00:00:00 to 11:59:55, twice per day.

Next, note that the transitions are always at 00:00:00.  We can easily detect these, as well as the first instance of each date:

```
twelve = ts.dt.time == datetime.time(0,0,0)
newdate = ts.dt.date.diff() > pd.Timedelta(0)
midnight = twelve & newdate
noon = twelve & ~newdate
```

Next, build an offset series, which should be easy to inspect for correctness:

```
offset = pd.Series(np.nan, ts.index, dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
offset[midnight] = pd.Timedelta(0)
offset[noon] = pd.Timedelta(12, 'h')
offset.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

And finally:

```
ts += offset
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my part, the initial .to_datetime() call does parse 12:00:00 as midnight 00:00:00. So I don't need the normalization step. Is 'twelve' a boolean Series with 'True' if the related hour starts with '00:mm:ss' ? Or only for the specific '00:00:00' transitions ? Because in my Series these transitions are not always at '00:00:00' and may be at 00:05:00 for example. And the 'newdate' Series displays 'True' only for the row corresponding to new date transition ?

Comment: Eventually, I understood your solution. But it works if all the transitions are 00:00:00 only. Some in my data Series are delayed of 5 or 10 seconds.

Comment: @T-DrumY: OK, I guess you'll need to make some minor adjustments to the code then.  For example you can set `twelve = (ts.dt.hour == 0) & (ts.dt.minute == 0)` then figure out how to keep that mask True only at the first time in each block.