# Sorting timestamps python

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I have a `pandas` `df` that contains a `Column` of `timestamps`. Some of the `timestamps` are after midnight. These are in 24hr time. I'm trying to add 12hrs to these times so it's consistent.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

d = ({           
    'time' : ['9:00:00','10:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00','01:00:00','02:00:00'], 
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have used the following code from another question. But I can't get it to include all the values. The dates are also not necessary.

[Convert incomplete 12h datetime-like strings into appropriate datetime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018182/convert-incomplete-12h-datetime-like-strings-into-appropriate-datetime-type/51083608#51083608)

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format = '%H:%M:%S')
ts[ts.dt.hour == 12] -= pd.Timedelta(12, 'h')
twelve = ts.dt.time == dt.time(0,0,0)
newdate = ts.dt.date.diff() > pd.Timedelta(0)
midnight = twelve & newdate
noon = twelve & ~newdate
offset = pd.Series(np.nan, ts.index, dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
offset[midnight] = pd.Timedelta(0)
offset[noon] = pd.Timedelta(12, 'h')
offset.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
ts = ts.add(offset, fill_value=0).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(ts)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

My intended Output is

```
       time
0   9:00:00
1  10:00:00
2  11:00:00
3  12:00:00
4  13:00:00
5  14:00:00
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018182/convert-incomplete-12h-datetime-like-strings-into-appropriate-datetime-type/51083608#51083608

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck. It has been useful

Comment: You're welcome.  Would you prefer that we close your question as a duplicate of that one, or would you like to write your own answer to your question (and later accept that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need change last row of code to [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with `fill_value=0` for repalce missing values to `ts` and then [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) for `python time`s or [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for `string`s:

```
ts = ts.add(offset, fill_value=0).dt.time
print (ts)
0    09:00:00
1    10:00:00
2    11:00:00
3    12:00:00
4    13:00:00
5    14:00:00
dtype: object

print (ts.apply(type))
0    <class 'datetime.time'>
1    <class 'datetime.time'>
2    <class 'datetime.time'>
3    <class 'datetime.time'>
4    <class 'datetime.time'>
5    <class 'datetime.time'>
dtype: object
```

---

```
ts = ts.add(offset, fill_value=0).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (ts)
0    09:00:00
1    10:00:00
2    11:00:00
3    12:00:00
4    13:00:00
5    14:00:00
dtype: object

print (ts.apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
5    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I'm getting an error though. ValueError: time data '13:00:00' does not match format '%I:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @PeterJames123 - So inpu data are different like in sample?

Comment: Same. I've updated the question to specifically display each line of code

Comment: @PeterJames123 - What is your pandas version? But I am also confused - there are not data after midnight?

Comment: @jezreal. Updated sorry. 0.19.2 is the version I'm using.

Comment: @PeterJames123 - Is possible upgrade? Tested in `0.23.1` and working nice.

Comment: Updated to 0.23.3. Not working. I'll have a look and see if anyone else has encountered this problem. Thanks @jezrael

Comment: @PeterJames123 - not working with sample data? Or with real data?

Comment: Sample date. I just closed and reopened the console. Works now!

Comment: @PeterJames123 - Supeeer, glad can help!