# How to add automatically missing AM/PM into a list of datetimes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a list of datetimes in 12-hour format but without the AM/PM info. The timestamps format is: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

I have tried to parse with both formating options

- '%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S'
- '%Y-%M-%d %I:%M:%S %p'  or without %p

but both failed to give the right result.

So I want to transform the whole list (let say for 288 samples = 1 day)

'2018-05-01 12:10:00'  to  '2018-05-01 12:10:00 AM'

....

'2018-05-01 06:20:00'  to  '2018-05-01 06:20:00 PM'

....

and so on..

Assume the timestamps are in 5min intervals. So we have 288 samples per day. The program needs to identify which entries are AM and which PM.

Answer (score 0):

This code solve this problem, I checked it with python 3.7

```
>>> import datetime
>>> someDate = '2019-09-29 16:32:00'                                                                                    
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(someDate , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
'2019-09-29 04:32:00 PM'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The timestamps are in 12h format (without AM/PM) and I want to do that for the whole list of 288 timestamps, not just a single one. Hense the program needs to identify which entries are AM and which PM. PS: I have edited the question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar topic

[Convert incomplete 12h datetime-like strings into appropriate datetime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018182/convert-incomplete-12h-datetime-like-strings-into-appropriate-datetime-type)

which solution can be used with small modifications to address my issue too.